# Function Objects vs State

Tags: c++, functor, std-function, stdbind

I have used function objects to find out what happens to the object that gets passed, and how it effects the state of the object. Here is a snippet of the test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
//#include <boost/function.hpp>
//using boost::function;

#include <functional>
using std::function;
using std::bind;

struct A {
  A() { std::cout << "Creating..." << "\n"; }
  void operator()() { call(); }
  void call() { std::cout << "Executing call..." << "\n"; }
  virtual ~A() { std::cout << "Destroying" << "\n"; }
};

typedef function<void ()> Func;

struct B{
  Func f;
  B(Func ff) : f(ff) {}
  void call() {f();}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  {
    A a;
    B b(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      b.call();
  }
  {
    A a2;
    B b2(bind(&A::call, &a2));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      b2.call();
  }
  return 0;
}

/** Output **
  Creating...
  Destroying
  Destroying
  Executing call...
  Executing call...
  Executing call...
  Executing call...
  Executing call...
  Destroying
  Destroying
  Creating...
  Executing call...
  Executing call...
  Executing call...
  Executing call...
  Executing call...
  Destroying
 */
```

When I pass the object with operator () overloaded, there is some multiple calls to destructors; and no objects are being created! So, I can not **rely**, so to say, on the fidelity of the object state. Does it mean that when I pass a function object (with overloaded operator()) for callback, I should assume that the state of the object is not preserved? **And is this, the intended behavior?**

On the other hand, callback to a bound member function from inside of an object of another type produces a *very stable behavior (I don't know what term to use)*; i.e. to say, I expected the object state to be preserved; and indeed it is! **Is this also an intended behaviour? IOW, is this how functors are generally understood?**

*PS:*

*I also checked it with boost::function and boost::bind --- The result is quite the similar. Probably another thread is required to discuss the nuances.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About "no constructors": There are calls to the copy constructor.

Try more instrumenting:

```
struct A {
  A() { std::cout << "Creating..." << "\n"; }
  void operator()() { call(); }
  A(const A&) { std::cout << "Copying" << "\n"; }
  A(A&&) { std::cout << "Moving" << "\n"; } // Assuming C++11
  void call() { std::cout << "Executing call..." << "\n"; }
  virtual ~A() { std::cout << "Destroying" << "\n"; }
};
```

About copying:

- You hand over the callable by value to B's constructor. It has to be copied.
- Bind, it is the intended behavior if you hand in a value. The callable you're handing to bind might be a temporary. Thus, the default behavior is to copy.

You can avoid this, by using a reference wrapper, if you know your callable will survive long enough (as is the case in your code). Try:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  {
    A a;
    {
      B b(a);
    }
    std::cout << "-------------\n";
    B(std::ref(a));
    std::cout << "-------------\n";
    B(bind(&A::call, a));
    std::cout << "-------------\n";
    B(bind(&A::call, &a));
    std::cout << "-------------\n";
    B(bind(&A::call, std::ref(a)));
    std::cout << "-------------\n";
  }
  std::cout << "-------------\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice explanation. The understanding of passing functor by reference, and the similarity with binding a function by reference was exemplary to the explanations! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> When I pass the object with operator () overloaded, there is some multiple calls to destructors; and no objects are being created!

You are not counting the objects that are constructed using the copy constructor, which is created by the compiler when you don't provide any.

Add a copy constructor to `A` and you will see the number of calls to the destructor to be the same as the calls to the constructors.

```
struct A {
  A() { std::cout << "Creating..." << "\n"; }

  // Add this
  A(A const& copy) { std::cout << "Creating..." << "\n"; }

  void operator()() { call(); }
  void call() { std::cout << "Executing call..." << "\n"; }
  virtual ~A() { std::cout << "Destroying" << "\n"; }
};
```